# Two way relationships in SQL queries

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database

I have a small database that is used to track parts. for the sake of this example the table looks like this:

**PartID** (PK), int 
**PartNumber**, Varchar(50), Unique 
**Description**, Varchar(255)

I have a requirement to define that certain parts are classified as similar to each other.
To do this I have setup a second table that looks like this:

**PartID**, (PK), int 
**SecondPartID**, (PK), int 
**ReasonForSimilarity**, Varchar(255)

Then a many-to-many relationship has been setup between the two tables.

The problem comes when I need to report on the parts that are considered similar because the relationship is two way I.E. if part *XYZ123* is similar to *ABC678* then *ABC678* is considered to be similar to *XYZ123*. So if I wanted to list all parts that are similar to a given part I either need to ensure the relationship is setup in both directions (which is bad because data is duplicated) or need to have 2 queries that look at the table in both directions. Neither of these solutions feels right to me.

So, how should this problem be approached? Can this be solved with SQL alone or does my design need to change to accommodate the business requirement?

Consider the following parts XYZ123, ABC123, ABC234, ABC345, ABC456 & EFG456 which have been entered into the existing structure entered above. You could end up with data that looks like this (omitting the reason field which is irrelevant at this point):

**PartID**, **SecondPartID** 
XYZ123, ABC123 
XYZ123, ABC234 
XYZ123, ABC345 
XYZ123, ABC456 
EFG456, XYZ123

My user wants to know *"Which parts are similar to XYZ123"*. This could be done using a query like so:

```
SELECT SecondPartID
FROM tblRelatedParts
WHERE PartID = 'XYZ123'
```

The problem with this though is it will not pick out part EFG456 which is related to XYZ123 despite the fact that the parts have been entered the other way round. It is feasible that this could happen depending on which part the user is currently working with and the relationship between the parts will *always* be two-way.

The problem I have with this though is that I now need to check that when a user sets up a relationship between two parts it does not already exist in the other direction.

**@Goran**

I have done some initial tests using your suggestion and this is how I plan to approach the problem using your suggestion.

The data listed above is entered into the new table (Note that I have changed the partID to part number to make the example clearer; the semantics of my problem haven't changed though)

The table would look like this:

**RelationshipID**, **PartNumber** 
1, XYZ123 
1, ABC123 
2, XYZ123 
2, ABC234 
3, XYZ123 
3, ABC345 
4, XYZ123 
4, ABC456 
5, EFG456 
5, XYZ123

I can then retrieve a list of similar parts using a query like this:

```
SELECT PartNumber
FROM tblPartRelationships
WHERE RelationshipID ANY (SELECT RelationshipID
                          FROM tblPartRelationships
                          WHERE PartNumber = 'XYZ123')
```

I'll carry out some more tests and if this works I'll feedback and accept the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've dealt with this issue by setting up a relationship table.

Part table:

**PartID** (PK), int

**PartNumber**, Varchar(50), Unique

**Description**, Varchar(255)

PartRelationship table:

**RelationshipId** (FK), int

**PartID** (FK), int

Relationship table:

**RelationshipId** (PK), int

Now similar parts simply get added to Relationship table:

RelationshipId, PartId

1,1

1,2

Whenever you add another part with relationshipId = 1 it is considered similar to any part with relationshipId = 1.

Possible API solutions for adding relationships:

- Create new relationship for each list of similar parts. Let client load, change and update the entire list whenever needed.
- Retrieve relationship(s) for a similar object. Filter the list by some criteria so that only one remains or let client choose from existing relationships. Create, remove PartRelationship record as needed.
- Retrieve list of relationships from Relationship table. Let client specify parts and relationships. Create, remove PartRelationship records as needed.

Comment: +1, although you might want to add an additional table to cater for the `ReasonForSimilarity` field, which is likely to be restricted to specific pairs (rather than applicable to all parts in a relationship).

Comment: @MarkBannister Good point. I'm not sure what all the requirements are but this should get OP pointed in the right direction. If there's any need for it I'll update my answer. @Benjamin?

Comment: + 1, this looks like a valid solution. I will do some tests and let you know how this goes. Just one thing regarding the relationship Id; how is this generated & maintained? presumably I'll need to ensure that the correct relationship is used when establishing a link between the parts to ensure this works. @MarkBannister I already have a separate table for ReasonForSimilarity but kept it out of the question as it does not affect what I want.

Comment: @Benjamin This really depends on your use-case. You could retrieve existing relationship from similar object (if there's only one or you can filter the list down to one), you can add a new relationship for list of objects (to group them)...

Comment: Very appreciated! I am working on a software rhyming dictionary that supports slant rhymes based on existing input, and was running into the same concerns regarding data duplication and/or multiple queries for the same relationship between phrasings. This suggestion is exactly what I need. +100 if I could :)

Answer (score 2):

Add a `CHECK` constraint e.g.

```
CHECK (PartID < SecondPartID);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but why not just do this query with your original schema?  Less tables and rows.

```
SELECT SecondPartID
FROM tblRelatedParts
WHERE PartID = 'XYZ123' 
UNION
SELECT PartID
FROM tblRelatedParts
WHERE SecondPartID = 'XYZ123'
```

I am dealing with a similar issue and looking at the two approaches and wondering why you thought the schema with the relationship table was better.  It seems like the original issue still exists in the sense that you still need to manage the relationships between them from both directions.

Comment: My original option has two tables whereas the selected answer only has one. I agree there are still some issues with the second option (which I still need to solve) but Gorans answer was the best at the time and was a good start in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

How about having two rows for each similarity. For example if you have objects A, B similar you will have in your relation table

```
A B
B A
```

I know you will double your relation data, but they are integers so it won't over kill your database. Instead you have some gains:

- you won't use union. Union is over kill in any dbms. Especially when you have order by or group by
- you can implement more specific relation: a is in relation with b, but b is not in relation with a. For example John can replace Dave, but Dave cannot replace John.